# Avoiding SQL injections with prepare and execute

Tags: perl, sql-injection, dbi

A line of code like

```
my $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user='$user';";
```

might introduce an SQL injection vulnerability into your program. To avoid this one could use something like

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user='?';");
$dbh->execute($user);
```

However, in the code I am currently working on the following is used

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user='" . $user . "';";
$dbh->prepare($sql_query);
$dbh->execute();
```

Does this actually work? If yes, are there any differences to what I would have done? What are the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: You want the second one, except without the single quotes around the question mark. They make it a string, not a parameter (and use `$sth->execute($user);` of course). The first and third are equivalent and have the same injection vulnerability.

Comment: @Shawn: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user='?'");
```

This won't work because it's searching for a literal `'?'` character — not a parameter. If you try to send a value for the parameter, MySQL will be like, "what do you want me to do with this?" because the query has no parameter placeholder.

If you want to use a parameter, you must NOT put the parameter placeholder inside string delimiters in the SQL query, even if the parameter will take string or datetime value:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user=?");
```

The next example:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user='" . $user . "'";
$dbh->prepare($sql_query);
$dbh->execute();
```

That will run the query, but it's NOT safe. You can prepare any query even if it has no parameters.

Using `prepare()` is not what makes queries safe from SQL injection. What makes it safer is using parameters to combine dynamic values instead of doing string-concatenation like you're doing in this example.

But using parameters does require the use of `prepare()`.

PS: You don't need to put `;` at the end of your SQL queries when you run them one at a time programmatically. The separator is only needed if you run multiple queries, like in an SQL script, or in a stored procedure. In your examples, the `;` is harmless but MySQL doesn't require it, and it will just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer and all the extra information!

Comment: I would add to this excellent answer that prepare isn't even necessary to use bound parameters safely. The second example is equivalent to `$dbh->do('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user=?', undef, $user);`, which depending on the DBI driver may optimize out the statement prepare step.